# supertest: ECONNRESET if more than 10 tests are run

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, hapi.js, supertest

I am trying to test my api served by hapi.js.

I settled for mocha, should and supertest.

The Problem is this: Every test and every combination of tests works as long as not more than 10 tests are called.
If more than 10 are called, hapi.js emits this error:

```
Debug: connection, client, error
  Error: read ECONNRESET
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:544:26)
```

and mocha this one:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
 at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alex\apflora_api\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:215:19)
```

I am using this code (extract):

```
'use strict'

const supertest = require('supertest')
const should = require('should')
const appPassFile = require('../appPass.json')

const server = supertest.agent('http://127.0.0.1:4001')

global.describe('/adressen', function () {
  global.it('should return more than 140 rows', function (done) {
    server
      .get('/adressen')
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.body.length.should.be.above(140)
        done()
      })
  })
})

global.describe('/anmeldung', function () {
  global.it('should accept known user', function (done) {
    const name = appPassFile.user
    const pwd = appPassFile.pass
    server
      .get(`/anmeldung/name=${name}/pwd=${pwd}`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status.should.equal(200)
        res.body.length.should.equal(1)
        done()
      })
  })
  global.it('should not accept unknown user', function (done) {
    server
      .get('/anmeldung/name=whoami/pwd=dontknow')
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.status.should.equal(200)
        res.body.length.should.equal(0)
        done()
      })
  })
})
```

I have tried this to solve the problem so far:

1 up the number of sockets

```
const http = require('http')
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity
```

This has no influence.

2 get the server differently

```
const app = require('../server.js')
app.address = () => '127.0.0.1:4001'
global.describe('hooks', function () {
  global.before(function () {
    app.start(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('Server running at:', app.info.uri)
    })
  })
})

const server = supertest('http://127.0.0.1:4001')
```

This produces the same errors.

3 Use

```
supertest('http://127.0.0.1:4001')
```

instead of

```
supertest.agent('http://127.0.0.1:4001')
```

This has no influence.

Every test is ended with a done callback.

I am getting the impression that supertest is meant to work with express.js. But I have not found a better solution yet.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you see if you add `console.log()`s just before each of the 10 `done()`s?

Comment: And whilst you're doing that, add logging for the errors you throw.

Comment: Have you looked at `server.inject()` instead of supertest? (http://hapijs.com/api#serverinjectoptions-callback)

Comment: @Clarkie Thanks for pointing out. I just tried it - with the same results (=errors) as before :-(

Comment: @AdrianLynch HUGE res objects are output, as there is a lot of data. But they look o.k. to me. err is always null.

Comment: @AdrianLynch here an example of the res output: https://gist.github.com/barbalex/3bdbcfc1c3e33ae26ece

Comment: So as soon as you add a 10th test, it fails?

Comment: And what about adding the logging just above the `done()`s, to prove they're being called.

Comment: @AdrianLynch the console.log's are shown until the 10th test. The 11th test fails and its console.log does not appear.

Comment: weird fact: If I add a console.log to the 10th test, this test (and the 11th) fail. But the console.log of the 10th test appears

Comment: Can we see the hapi server code your are exporting?  I suggest you look at hapi's tests for help and also strongly advise you use lab and code along with server.inject to test api. Econnreset may mean something in superagent is timing out

Comment: @simon-p-r here is the server code: https://github.com/FNSKtZH/apflora_api/blob/master/server.js

Comment: and here are the tests: https://github.com/FNSKtZH/apflora_api/blob/master/test/test.js

Comment: @simon-p-r what do you mean with use "lab" and "code"? I could not find this in the hapi api

Comment: They are modules written by core hapi members, here is [lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab) and here is [code](https://github.com/hapijs/code).  Look at the test in the hapi repo and test your api that way.  Your tests don't look like they are starting the server properly.

Comment: @simon-p-r So THAT is how to test in hapi.js. I like the modularity and the speed. Will tell you if the problem is solved once I have converted more than 10 tests

Comment: Well, nice way to test or not: With more than 10 tests, this fails just the same :-(

Comment: here is the new code using lab and code: https://github.com/FNSKtZH/apflora_api/tree/master/test

Comment: You must call [start](http://hapijs.com/api#serverstartcallback) or [initialize](http://hapijs.com/api#serverinitializecallback) on server object before you can use server.inject for testing

Comment: Uups. Why is that not done in tests in hapi.js? See: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/test/reply.js

Comment: By the way: Thanks for stellar help!